# Implementation of Paypal REST API in Python

Tags: python, rest, paypal

I've been following PayPal [directions](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/python?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox) to implement its REST API in Python, but I'm missing some key pieces of the puzzle and I don't know where to find them. So far I have the following code to start processing a payment:

```
api = paypalrestsdk.set_config(
    mode="sandbox", 
    client_id="XXX", 
    client_secret="XXX")

api.get_token()

payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": { "payment_method": "paypal" },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "https://XXX",
        "cancel_url": "https://XXX" },

    "transactions": [ {
        "amount": {
            "total": "50",
            "currency": "USD" },
        "description": "creating a payment" 
        } ] 
    } )

payment.create()
```

So far, so good (though I don't know what to do with the token I get...).
Here begin my problems (or lack or knowledge). First, I need the `approval url`. And then, in the next steps, I don't know how to get the information needed to process the execution of the payment: `payment id` and `payer id`

```
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find("XXX")
payment.execute({"payer_id": "XXX"})
```

These last two lines are key to make the transaction happen. Where do I get their arguments?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating the `payment.create()`, You have to get `payment.id` and save it in user session.

And redirect the user to approve url. Use below code to get the approval url:

```
  for link in payment.links:
    if link.method == "REDIRECT":
      redirect_url = link.href
      print("Redirect for approval: %s"%(redirect_url))
```

Use the `payment.id` from user session and `PayerID` from `return_url` to execute the payment.

Samples:

- [create payment](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_paypal.py)
- [execute payment](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/blob/master/samples/payment/execute.py)

Comment: Siddick, thank you for your answer. I'm now clear about where you get the `approval url` and the `payment id`. But, where do you get the `payer id`? Thanks.

Comment: `PayerID` will be in the `return_url`, after completing the approve process. Example return url: `https://XXX/?PayerID=DUFRQ8GWYMJXC`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

When the user approves the payment, PayPal redirects the user to the return_url that was specified when the payment was created. A **payer Id** and **payment Id** are appended to the return URL, as PayerID and paymentId:

http://return_url?**paymentId**=PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y&token=EC-60U79048BN7719609&**PayerID**=7E7MGXCWTTKK2

From https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

Answer (score 0):

First, get the payment id after creating payment and save it in the user session like this:

```
if payment.create():
    print('Payment success!')
    request.session["payment_id"] = payment.id
else:
    print(payment.error)
```

After that write function for execute payment and get "Payer id" from returned url:

```
def execute(request):
    success = False
    payment_id = request.session["payment_id"]
    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(payment_id)
    if payment.execute({'payer_id':request.POST.get("payerID")}):
        print('Execute success!')
        success = True
    else:
        print(payment.error)
```

Thank you